# How to embed an Instrumentation Manifest without losing the AssemblyInfo?

Tags: .net, etw

My goal is to embed an instrumentation manifest in a .NET assembly.
To do that, I compile the manifest file (.man) into a resource file (.rc) using mc.exe, then compile the .rc file into a .res file using rc.exe. Finally, I use the Win32Resource element in the .csproj file to embed the .res file into my assembly.

The problem is that once I use the Win32Resource element, I lose the versioning info generated by the AssemblyInfo.cs file.

How can I both embed the instrumentation manifest and keep the versioning info in the resulting assembly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the [Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource](https://web.archive.org/web/20160119184026/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/01/30/microsoft-diagnostics-tracing-eventsource-rtms.aspx) NuGet Package to use ETW in .Net.

Here is a sample class:

```
[EventSource(Name = "Samples-EventSourceDemos-EventLog")]
public sealed class MinimalEventSource : EventSource
{
    public static MinimalEventSource Log = new MinimalEventSource();

    [Event(1, Message="{0} -> {1}", Channel = EventChannel.Admin)]
    public void Load(long baseAddress, string imageName)
    {
        WriteEvent(1, baseAddress, imageName);
    }
}
```

This is much better compared to the old C++ way.

Comment: fixed the broken URL in the answer above by pointing to an archive.org copy of that page (shame on Microsoft and other companies for breaking the web like that)

Comment: That article points to https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource and 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventRegister and the page of the EventSource NuGet package references https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventsource?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1